Tengo dudas sobre como usar el método trim()
estoy aprendiendo Java (es el primer lenguaje que aprendo) y comencé a complementar las lecciones de la escuela con Excersim y me agrada bastante porque después de cada lección te permite comparar tus respuestas con las de otros usuarios y puedes ver que hay mil maneras resolver el mismo problema. Vi dos ejemplos de respuestas de alguien mas que me llamaron la atención particularmente, porque no logro entender muy bien que hacen (el tema es String y sus métodos: trim, substring, format)
El primero es este:
import static java.lang.String.format;

public class LogLevels {

  public static String message(String logLine) {
    return logLine.split("]: ")[1].trim();
  }

  public static String logLevel(String logLine) {
    return logLine.split("]: ")[0].substring(1).toLowerCase();
  }

  public static String reformat(String logLine) {
    return format("%s (%s)", message(logLine), logLevel(logLine));
  }
}

Las líneas que no entiendo son:
return logLine.split("]: ")[1].trim();

y
return logLine.split("]: ")[0].substring(1)

Por que aparece esto: [1] [0] como si fuera el índice de un arreglo a algo así? (o creo que lo estoy entendiendo mal)
El segundo es este:
public class LogLevels {

  public static String message(String logLine) {
    return logLine.substring(logLine.indexOf(":") + 1).trim();
  }

  public static String logLevel(String logLine) {
    return logLine.substring(
      logLine.indexOf("[") + 1, logLine.indexOf("]")
    ).toLowerCase();
  }

  public static String reformat(String logLine) {
    return message(logLine) + " (" + logLevel(logLine) + ")";
  }
}

Aqui la linea que no entiendo es esta:
return logLine.substring(
  logLine.indexOf("[") + 1,
  logLine.indexOf("]")
).toLowerCase();

Porque le está sumando un 1? A que se lo está sumando  exactamente si esos son caracteres? y no números. Si alguien pudieras explicarme esas líneas se lo agradeceria muchisimo, este tema me confundió bastante. En verdad agradezco la ayuda

Después de la excelente respuesta de Stina Andersson, queda poco que agregar, pero trataré de dejar más claro este tema.
Vamos por partes.
Este código funciona perfectamente:
String frase = " Mi palabra ";

  // el método "trim", quita los espacios al principio y al final
String fraseLimpiaDeEspacios = frase.trim();

  // el método "split" crea un array, usando como separador, la cadena pasada como argumento
  // en este caso, un espacio en blanco. 
String partesDeLaFrase[] = fraseLimpiaDeEspacios.split( " " );

  // aquí, simplemente tomamos la cadena que está en la primer posición del array
String primerPalabraEnFrase = partesDeLaFrase[ 0 ];

  // el método "substring" devuelve la cadena contenida entra las posiciones pasadas
  // como argumento (la primer posición contenida y la segunda excluida)
String primerLetraDeLaPrimerPalabra = primerPalabraEnFrase.substring( 0, 1 );

Hasta aquí, todo maravilloso, pero supongamos que solo necesito usar primerLetraDeLaPrimerPalabra, entonces podrías simplificar mi código así:
String frase = " Mi palabra ";

  // agrupo en una linea las dos primeras operaciones
String partesDeLaFrase[] = fraseLimpiaDeEspacios.trim().split( " " );

Esta linea se entiende así, fraseLimpiaDeEspacios.trim() devuelve un String y esa cadena es recibida por split que hace lo suyo.
Siempre tienes que pensar en terminos de 'que devuelve esta operación'.
Podemos seguir simplificando:
  // tomamos la primer posición del array
String primerPalabraEnFrase = fraseLimpiaDeEspacios.trim().split( " " )[ 0 ];

Ya habiamos visto que el conjunto fraseLimpiaDeEspacios.trim().split( " " ), nos devolvía un array, así que solo tomamos su primer item con [ 0 ].
Por último, tomamos la primer letra:
  // bueno esta explicación es más de lo mismo...
String primerLetraDeLaPrimerPalabra = fraseLimpiaDeEspacios.trim().split( " " )[ 0 ].substring( 0, 1 );

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas.

En el primer código:
logLine.split("]: ")[1].trim();

Explicación: split("]: ") divide el string en dos partes usando "]: " como delimitador. [1] accede a la segunda parte (después del ]: ). trim() elimina los espacios al inicio y final.

logLine.split("]: ")[0].substring(1)

Explicación: [0] accede a la primera parte (antes de ]: ). substring(1) omite el primer carácter ([) para obtener solo el texto entre los corchetes.

En el segundo código:
logLine.substring(logLine.indexOf("[") + 1, logLine.indexOf("]")).toLowerCase();

Explicación: indexOf("[") encuentra la posición del primer [. Se suma 1 para omitir ese carácter. indexOf("]") encuentra la posición de ]. El substring extrae el texto entre esos índices.

